# Modifying machine.config on Azure compute instances

Tags: azure

I want to change the process model, unfortunately this is not allowed in runtime or in your Web Role `web.config` file, the setting is only allowed in the `machine.config` file.

```
<processModel maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="50"/>
```

What is the best way to go about changing the machine.config file on *all* Azure compute instances at once?

The default process model settings are not optimal for my application:

> Minimum number of worker threads per CPU in the CLR thread pool: 1
>
> Maximum amount of worker threads per CPU in the CLR thread pool: 20
>
> Maximum number of I/O threads per CPU in the CLR thread pool: 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, make changes like this in startup tasks. A batch file running `appcmd` is probably the easiest way to do it for IIS settings.

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation I found that `maxWorkerThreads` has been replaced by `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` after IIS 7 and .NET 4 was released , see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/cbc1f1bb-9ff6-4fef-8ef2-fa3547747449/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050(v=bts.10).aspx for more information.