# How can I enable <deployment retail="true" /> by default on Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, azure, machine.config

It seems that using **<deployment retail="true" />** is an accepted best practice for ASP.NET applications, but it does not seem to be enabled by default on Windows Azure. Is it possible to enable by default on Web Roles and/or Web Sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would do this with a startup task. See @smarx's answer here: [Modifying machine.config on Azure compute instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777395/modifying-machine-config-on-azure-compute-instances)

> A batch file running appcmd is probably the easiest way to do it for
>   IIS settings.

Some resources:

[MSDN: How to Define Startup Tasks for a Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx)

[Azure: How to execute startup tasks for each site entry at webrole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189638/azure-how-to-execute-startup-tasks-for-each-site-entry-at-webrole)

[Utilizing the Power of Startup Tasks in Your Windows Azure Web Role](http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/01/utilizing-the-power-of-startup-tasks-in-your-windows-azure-web-role/)

And, specific to managing machine.config from a startup task:

https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/azure-webroleperformance-scripts